# Fill a Table with an arrayview android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

Hello I'd need to create and fill a table, im trying do it like ListView-ArrayAdapter does.
Can I do it that way or i shoud make 2 bucles (horizontal and vertical) inflate each cell and insert it in the corresponding row?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with a custom ArrayAdapter, just have to override getView in the adapter and inflate a custom layout. see [ListView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)